# Error in running Spark-Scala example in intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I Build Scala Project in Intellij and I try to run an Apache Spark example. Here is my code :

```
package sparkTraining

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object SimpleApp {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
   val logFile = "/usr/local/spark/README.md"
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
   val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
   val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
   println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")
   sc.stop()
 }
}
```

I have installed Scala and SBT plugin on Intellij and here is my **build.sbt** code:

```
name := "sparkTraining"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.0"
```

and I added all Saprk 2.0.1 jars to the project. But the problem is when I run this piece of code it **errors**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCallSite(Utils.scala:1410)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:77)
at sparkTraining.SimpleApp$.main(testScala.scala:9)
at sparkTraining.SimpleApp.main(testScala.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I searched for it and I couldn't find any useful answer.

Here is some **points**:

- I have two user, **user1** and **hduser**, and all my Big Data project like Hadoop, Spark and Scala are under hduser and all paths are set in hduser .bashrc, while Intellij is under root (in /opt folder).
- while executing this code Spark is not running in my machine.

These two points have any affect on executing?
How can I solved my problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Please post all your dependencies as well

Comment: it is due to scala version mismatch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it because incompatible of scala version，the official Documents tell that You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).
[official Documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIkMx.png)